# encodeURIComponent on dynamic request url, node.js

Tags: node.js, url, request, encode, node-http-proxy

I am requesting an index.djvu that fires requests for documents by id. The requests id that the index.djvu fires is Base64 encoded e.g *`document/page_1_1_1_k21g_MjE4MGstMTAvMTE=.djvu`* where the id is *`MjE4MGstMTAvMTE=`*.
I need to encode the id before the requests is sent e.g `encodeURIComponent('MjE4MGstMTAvMTE=')`.
How can I get control over the requests that the index.djvu fires?

My code looks like this

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var HttpProxyRules = require('http-proxy-rules');

var proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
  rules: {
    // This requests response index further requests explained
    '.*/document': 'https://api.service.xxx/document/index.djvu?archive=21&id=2180k-10/11'
  },
  default: 'https://api.service.xxx/document'
});

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  secure: false
});

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');

});

var server = {};
server.httpServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var target = proxyRules.match(req);
  if (target) {
    return proxy.web(req, res, {
      target: target
    });
  }
});

server.init = () => {
  server.httpServer.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'The HTTP server is running on port 9000');
  });
}
server.init();

server.httpServer.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error http-server\n', JSON.stringify(err));
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
  console.log('Status: ' + proxyRes.statusCode + ' ' + proxyRes.statusMessage);
  proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('Body: ' + chunk.toString('utf8'));
  });
  console.log('Headers received from api: ', JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers, true, 2));
});
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This solved it after several hours of war ;)

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var url = require('url');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: 'https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx',
  secure: false
}).listen(9000);

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
  var str = url_parts.pathname;
  var query = url_parts.search;
  if (str) {
    var path = str.split("_");
    urlstring = {
      page_: path[0],
      vers: path[1],
      subdoc: path[2],
      page: path[3],
      archive: path[4],
      enc_id: path[5]
    }
  }
  var rewritedPath;
  if (str.includes('route')) {
    rewritedPath = '/xxx' + str;
  } else if (str.includes('route')) {
    var index = '/xxx' + str + query;
    rewritedPath = index;
  } else {
    var page = 'xxx' + urlstring.page_ + '_' + urlstring.vers + '_' + urlstring.subdoc + '_' + urlstring.page + '_' + urlstring.archive + '_' + encodeURIComponent(urlstring.enc_id);
    rewritedPath = page;
  }
  proxyReq.path = rewritedPath;
});

proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
  console.log('Something went wrong.', err);
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
  // console.log('Status: ' + req.url + ' ' + proxyRes.statusMessage);
  // proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
  //   console.log('Body: ' + chunk.toString('utf8'));
  // });
  // console.log('Headers: ', JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers, true, 2));
});
```